# Secure Spring security login and logout in Portal style applications using iFrames

Tags: spring-security, portal

[image: PortalApp]

I am involved in development of a portal style application. The diagram above shows the core UI wireframe of the application. There is one main application **mainApp** which acts as the portal application. It contains a sidebar menu which provides "entry points" to launch various other web applications (App1, App2... AppN) which are independent, separately packaged and deployed war files, running in same Tomcat server as **mainApp**.

All applications are Spring (3.2.x) based and have spring-security (3.2.x) integrated. User only logs into mainApp using spring security's standard login form mechanism. Obvious expectation is that the user does not have to login to each individual application they launch from sidebar menu. Same user should be logged into each of the launched application automatically.

App1, App2,... AppN are loaded via their respective URLs in an iFrame within the mainApp's page as illustrated in the diagram as well.

As a very rudimentary first iteration, I have implemented a filter extending Spring's **[AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html)** in each of the portal applications. The filter looks for a URL parameter **authToken** and automatically logs the user in, if the parameter is found and is Base64 (I know, very weak!) decoded to be the user name. If token is not found, user might see a spring security login screen inside iFrame (ugly).

Questions:

1. Is there a better, more secure way compared to query parameter, to pass the authentication token or ticket to the application being launched inside the iFrame? I presume I can not use request headers as there is no way to pass them when main portal app sets the URL in iFrame? Or is there a way? Or any other mechanism?
2. When the user logs out of the mainApp, how do I log the user out of each of the App1, App2...AppN that user has launched and got pre-authenticated into? Programatically hit the spring security `/logout` endpoint in each application when logout occurs in main portal app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea:
You can set spring security login page to another page which redirect parent to login page:

spring security config:

```
formLogin().loginPage("/redirect_login.jsp")
```

redirect_login.jsp:

```
window.parent.location.href="./login.jsp"
```